# Why is vercel showing a white screen?

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I am trying to deploy my portfolio website. It shows the proper log-in animation but then just shows a white screen. I have no idea why this is happening, the logged error message references unhelpful code from the site generator.

Comment: You can check the console, you got some errors which should give some insight about fixing the error. 

Something like you're trying to map skillsSection.skills which seemed to be undefined. You can use optional chaining rather or make it skillsSection.skills && skillsSection.skills?.mao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is in console. and in Skills.js file in line 48.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

you can fixed it by adding question mark like this :

```
 { skillsSection.skills?.map((skills, i)=> ....
```

and there is another error : `twitter.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')`
in twitter.js file in line 14

just add question mark there too. like this :

```
if (!document.getElementById("twitter")?.innerHTML.includes("iframe"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought that line was something from the DOM I couldn't see directly in React